# Load the result of LINQ XML file to datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I have an xml file. And I want to load just the content of "Project1" and sort to "TaskID".

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Contents>
  <Project Project="Project1">
    <TaskV>Hello</TaskV>
    <TaskE>Goodbye</TaskE>
    <taskID>1</taskID>
  </Project>
  <Project Project="Project1">
    <TaskV>Nice to meet you</TaskV>
    <TaskE>Let's go</TaskE>
    <taskID>2</taskID>
  </Project>
  <Project Project="Project2">
    <TaskV>This is my book</TaskV>
    <TaskE>This is my pen</TaskE>
    <taskID>1</taskID>
  </Project>
  <Project Project="Project2">
    <TaskV>Look for a cat</TaskV>
    <TaskE>Near the library</TaskE>
    <taskID>2</taskID>
  </Project>
<Contents>
```

My code:

```
private void loaddata()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\result.xml");
            var query = from project in doc.Descendants("Contents")
                        where (string)project.Element("Project") == "Project1"
                        select new 
                        {
                            V = project.Element("TasKV").Value,
                            E = project.Element("TaskE").Value
                        };
          dataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
        }
```

My xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="XML.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XML"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="420" Width="1327.471">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="1268" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I can load all data in XML file to datagrid, but when I use linq to get just data "Project1", it's not work.

Anyone can  help  me to solve this problem. Sorry if my English is terrible.

Comment: Set the data context of dataGrid using `dataGrid.DataContext = query;` or remove the override of `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` from xaml.

Comment: I tried to use datagGrid.DataContext=query like you said, but it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\result.xml");
var query = doc.Root.Elements("Project")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("Project").Value == "Project1")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    V = x.Element("TaskV").Value,
                    E = x.Element("TaskE").Value
                });
dataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
```

Comment: It has an error after "... });". The error is "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XML.exe but was not handled in user code". Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Update: Your code is perfect. I have a spelling mistake in code. "TaskV" not "TasKV". Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

**A few remarks:**

Your XML file is not closed properly. the last element should be `</Contents>` and not `<Contents>`

In this line `V = project.Element("TasKV").Value` has a misspelled `TaskV` (the k is should be lowercase).

`private void loaddata()` should be `LoadData` as per the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)

**The solution:**

```cs
var query = from project in doc.Root.Elements("Project")
            where project.Value == "Project1"
            select new
            {
                V = project.Element("TaskV").Value,
                E = project.Element("TaskE").Value
            };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The mistake is "TasKV". The correct is "TaskV".

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(your xml file or data);
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataView
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want just load the data of "Project1". Your code will load all Project1 and Project2...